# Adding months in where clause in sql

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am writing a sp for getting the data for the next 6 months for a particular date field,

```
SELECT CR.[Id] AS ClaimId
    ,CR.[BOLNumber]
    ,CR.[PRONumber]
    ,CR.[ClaimNumber]
    ,CR.[CompanyName]
    ,c.NAME AS CarrierName
    ,CR.[DateFiled]
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CR.[DateFiled], 103) AS DateFiledString
    ,CR.[ClaimDate] AS ClaimReceivedDate
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CR.[ClaimDate], 103) AS ClaimReceivedDateString
    ,CR.[AmountFiled]
    ,CR.[Status] AS StatusId
    ,CR.[SettledAmount]
FROM CarrierRate.Claims AS CR WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CR.CustomerId = @AccountUserId AND
 CR.Status = @statusType AND CR.ClaimDate < DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)
ORDER BY CR.[Status] ASC
```

The field is ClaimDate. So am i doing it right or anything to be changed?
Please suggest

Comment: You should add another condition to ensure the date range starts from today or whenever. Otherwise, you will get all the results where `ClaimDate` is before 6 months from now.

Comment: `CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(month, 6, GETDATE())` note that `CR.ClaimDate < DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)` is always true (except at the end of an epoch, 2038 anyone?)

Comment: i have added this `AND CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN CR.ClaimDate AND DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)` since i want to select all the data within the six months of ClaimDate

Comment: @Aron i am using this `CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)`. I want one more condition to be added. the above statment should be executed only when `@statusType=2`.

Comment: That isn't what it's doing...

Comment: @Aron Ya so whats the catch for that, i appreciate your patience.Please help me out with this.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "Within the six months of ClaimDate". ClaimDate is a column on the row. Do you mean within 6 months of a date that is a PARAMETER? All I know is that logically what you have already CANNOT MAKE SENSE, since its tautological.

Comment: @Aron: That means if my claim date is 01/01/2015, i want the data to be filtered from 01/07/2014, 6 months. Hope i am making sense.Thanks for your patience

Comment: What does " i want the data to be filtered from 01/07/2014, 6 months" mean?

Comment: @Aron: I want the data from that table between 01/07/2014 to 01/01/2015.

Comment: Why "01/07/2014 to 01/01/2015"? Because its 01/01/2015 today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
CONVERT(DATE, CR.ClaimDate) < DATEADD(MONTH,6,CONVERT(DATE, CR.ClaimDate))
```

only date is considered here.

Comment: i have added this `AND CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN CR.ClaimDate AND DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)` since i want to select all the data within the six months of ClaimDate

Answer (score 0):

Use [**BETWEEN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187922.aspx) keyword to specify date range.

```
WHERE CR.CustomerId = @AccountUserId AND
 CR.Status = @statusType AND
 CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)
```

Comment: Kumar note my comment. You effectively have `CR.ClaimDate > GETDATE()` but slower due to non-determinism. `x < x + 6 ` is ALWAYS true.

Comment: @Kumar i have added this 'AND CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN CR.ClaimDate AND DATEADD(month,6,CR.ClaimDate)' since i want to select all the data within the six months of ClaimDate

Answer (score 0):

```
 (CR.ClaimDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
   OR @statusType <> 2)
```